# Running Scully in an Angular 15 Project?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, scully, angular-scully

I'm upgrading a Angular 12 project to an Angular 15 project and attempting to run scully on it again.

Before this worked fine.

```
ng add @scullyio/init --skip-confirmation --defaults
ng build
npx scully --
```

Now it produces this error:

```
      =====================================================================================================
      Config file "./scully.undefined.config.ts" not found, only rendering routes without parameters
      The config file should have a name that is formated as:
          scully.<projectName>.config.ts
      where <projectName> is the name of the project as defined in the 'angular.json' file
      If you meant to build a different project as undefined you can use:
          --project differentProjectName as a cmd line option

      When you are in a mixed mono-repo you might need to use the --pjFirst flag.
       which will look for package.json instead of angular.json to find the 'root' of the project.
    =====================================================================================================
```

The `angular.json` file looks like this.  The `<projectName>` is `fs-developer-app`.

```
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "fs-developer-app": {
      "projectType": "application",
      "schematics": {
        "@schematics/angular:component": {
          "style": "scss",
          "skipTests": true
        },
        "@schematics/angular:class": {
          "skipTests": true
        },
        "@schematics/angular:directive": {
          "skipTests": true
        },
        "@schematics/angular:guard": {
          "skipTests": true
        },
        "@schematics/angular:interceptor": {
          "skipTests": true
        },
        "@schematics/angular:pipe": {
          "skipTests": true
        },
        "@schematics/angular:resolver": {
          "skipTests": true
        },
        "@schematics/angular:service": {
          "skipTests": true
        }
      },
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "src",
      "prefix": "app",
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist/fs-developer-app",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "main": "src/main.ts",
            "polyfills": [
              "zone.js"
            ],
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
            "inlineStyleLanguage": "scss",
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css",
              "src/styles.scss"
            ],
            "scripts": []
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "budgets": [
                {
                  "type": "initial",
                  "maximumWarning": "10MB",
                  "maximumError": "20MB"
                },
                {
                  "type": "anyComponentStyle",
                  "maximumWarning": "2kb",
                  "maximumError": "4kb"
                }
              ],
              "outputHashing": "all"
            },
            "development": {
              "buildOptimizer": false,
              "optimization": false,
              "vendorChunk": true,
              "extractLicenses": false,
              "sourceMap": true,
              "namedChunks": true
            }
          },
          "defaultConfiguration": "production"
        },
        "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "browserTarget": "fs-developer-app:build:production"
            },
            "development": {
              "browserTarget": "fs-developer-app:build:development"
            }
          },
          "defaultConfiguration": "development"
        },
        "extract-i18n": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "fs-developer-app:build"
          }
        },
        "test": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
          "options": {
            "polyfills": [
              "zone.js",
              "zone.js/testing"
            ],
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.spec.json",
            "inlineStyleLanguage": "scss",
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css",
              "src/styles.scss"
            ],
            "scripts": []
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```
And the `scully.fs-developer-app.config.ts` looks like this:
```

```
import { ScullyConfig } from '@scullyio/scully';
export const config: ScullyConfig = {
  projectRoot: "./src",
  projectName: "fs-developer-app",
  outDir: './dist/static',
  routes: {
  },
  extraRoutes: ['/blogs','/guides','/tasks','/formulas','/concepts','/examples','/blogs/blogs--design--the-human-algorithm-for-learning','/blogs/blogs--design--the-power-of-the-simplest-possible-example','/guides/guides--introduction-to-the-firefly-semantics-slice-reactive-entity-store','/guides/guides--introduction-to-the-firefly-semantics-slice-reactive-object-store','/guides/guides--recreating-the-ngrx-demo-app-with-firefly-semantics-slice-state-manager','/guides/guides--dexie--browser-big-data-with-dexie-and-typescript','/guides/guides--macos--mac-os-keyboard-shortcuts'
... etc
```

## Update

The answer provided by KaliaHayes looks promising and I tried it once, and it "Almost" worked, so I'm going to try it fresh again with all the steps outlined here:

First I recreated the entire projects fresh.  Then built it:

```
ng build
```

Next install Scully puppeteer:

```
npm install @scullyio/scully-plugin-puppeteer
```

Try running scully:

```
npx scully --project fs-developer-app
```

This results in:

```
=================================================================================================
Puppeteer cannot find or launch the browser. (by default chrome)
 Try adding 'puppeteerLaunchOptions: {executablePath: CHROMIUM_PATH}'
 to your scully.*.config.ts file.
Also, this might happen because the default timeout (60 seconds) is to short on this system
this can be fixed by adding the --serverTimeout=x cmd line option.
   (where x = the new timeout in milliseconds)
When this happens in CI/CD you can find some additional information here:
https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/main/docs/troubleshooting.md
=================================================================================================
```

I'm on MacOS, so [I found the launch path like this](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/95837/find-google-chrome-installation-directory-using-terminal):

```
osascript -e 'POSIX path of (path to application "Chrome")'
```

Then added it to the config like this:

```
export const config: ScullyConfig = {
  puppeteerLaunchOptions: {executablePath: '/Applications/Google Chrome.app/'},
...
```

Tried again, but I still get the same error.  So I try adding the `--serverTimeout=x` command line option:

```
 npx scully --project fs-developer-app --serverTimeout=300000
```

Still get the same error ...

Comment: https://github.com/scullyio/scully/issues/1659

Comment: Given the project last had update Sept 22 and Angular 15 was released Nov 22 it looks like the library will need some tlc from the community and maintainers in order to keep up to date with the angular lts schedule

Comment: @AndrewAllen lets keep our fingers crossed :)

Comment: If not there's analogjs, which I know took a lot of inspiration from this scully repo

Comment: Oh wow!!  Thank you for pointing that out.  Checking it out now!!  Thank you SO MUCH!!

Answer (score 1):

Try adding in `angular.json`:

```
{
    "defaultProject": "fs-developer-app",
}
```

Apparently `defaultProject` was dropped in Angular 14 but Scully still uses it.

Comment: That looked promising ... I wish it would work ... but no love ...

Comment: https://blog.herodevs.com/how-to-add-scully-to-your-angular-15-application-b9472aa19ebc

Comment: I changed the answer a bit based on the writeup by one of the Scully developers.

Answer (score 1):

Try specifying your project name:

```
ng add @scullyio/init --skip-confirmation --defaults
ng build
npx scully --project fs-developer-app
```

[Source](https://github.com/scullyio/scully/issues/1625#issuecomment-1519071971)

Overall, I'm sure the next Scully update will mitigate these issues. I would also recc. checking out Analogjs in the meantime.

Comment: Hi Kalia.  That looked promising.  I tried it out 2 times and added my notes to the question reflecting the second attempt.  Also Welcome to SO!!

Answer (score 0):

in this part you need add "default project: {name-of-project}"

```
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "defaultProject": "your project name",
  "projects": {
```

Comment: Hi Daniel - Welcome to SO.  We have tried that and many other things and no love so far.  There's a trace of the things we've tried in this Github issue: https://github.com/scullyio/scully/issues/1659